# Calculate occurrence of property in a list of objects and convert objects to list of new objects with that counter

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a list of `Person` objects. `id` is one of properties of `Person` class. The list can contain duplicates of the Person with the same id and different other properties.

Now I need to calculate the occurrences of the same `id` and after that convert the grouped `Persons` ordered by `timestamp` to another object which has the property `occurrences`.

I came up with something like this and I'm wondering if there is any way to simplify this process:

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
    new Person("A", "2021-12-27"), 
    new Person("B", "2021-12-26"), 
    new Person("A", "2021-12-25")
);

Map<String, Long> personToOccurrence = persons
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getUserName, Collectors.counting()));

List<NewClass> convertedPersonsWithOccurrences = persons
    .stream()
    .filter(distinctByKey(Person::getUserName))
    .map(i -> convertToNewClass(i, personToOccurrence.get(i.getUserName())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
class Person {
   String id;
   Date timestamp;
}
                    
private static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

So in the `convertedPersonsWithOccurrences` I expect to have:

```
NewClass("A", "2021-12-27", 2)
NewClass("B", "2021-12-26", 1)
```

where the last attribute is the occurrence of `id` attribute in `persons` list.

**EDIT:**

In general, those classes has been simplified. In real case, `convertToNewClass` should accept a whole object which has multiple fields and convert it to new class. So that's why I gave example of passing whole `Person` object and occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toMap` collector with merge function. in merge function you need to compare `Timestamp` property and increment `count` value.

*Use `LocalDate` instead `Date`*

```
 persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId,
                    v -> new NewClass(v.id, v.getTimestamp(), 1l),
                    (o1, o2) -> {
                        if (o1.getTimestamp().isAfter(o2.getTimestamp())) {
                            o1.setCount(o1.getCount() + 1l);
                            return o1;
                        } else {
                            o2.setCount(o2.getCount() + 1l);
                            return o2;
                        }
                    })).values();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. What do you think also about answer posted by Shawn? Yours have just one stream, but update counter afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a map of user ids, you can skip the distinct stuff in the second calculation by looking at the keys of the map, which are by definition going to be distinct.

If you use the base `groupingBy()` instead of adding a downstream `counting()` collector so you get a list of each group of `Person`s, it will make getting the newest (Or oldest) timestamp of each group easy.

Self-contained Java 17+ example:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Demo {
    private static record Person(String id, Date timestamp) {}
    private static record NewClass(String id, Date timestamp, int count) {}

    private static Date makeDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.clear();
        c.set(year, month - 1, day);
        return c.getTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = List.of(new Person("A", makeDate(2021, 12, 27)),
                                       new Person("B", makeDate(2021, 12, 26)),
                                       new Person("A", makeDate(2021, 12, 25)));
        Map<String, List<Person>> groupedPersons =
            persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::id));
        List<NewClass> convertedPersonsWithOccurences =
            groupedPersons.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new NewClass(e.getKey(),
                                   e.getValue().stream()
                                    .max((a, b) -> a.timestamp.compareTo(b.timestamp))
                                    .orElseThrow()
                                    .timestamp,
                                   e.getValue().size()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(convertedPersonsWithOccurences);
    }
}
```

displays

```
[NewClass[id=A, timestamp=Mon Dec 27 00:00:00 PST 2021, count=2], NewClass[id=B, timestamp=Sun Dec 26 00:00:00 PST 2021, count=1]]
```

when run.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I've updated my question, where I gave info that I need to pass the whole object. So I adjusted your code to my needs. But the question is your answer has advantages over Hadi's example? Yours have 3 streams, there is only one